# Difference between swig.compileFile and swig.render

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I have recently switched from jade template engine to swig in node-js application. while using jade i used command 
`jade.render('/sample.jade',{obj:object});` 
to render template and pass objects. now when i am moving to swig the same 
thing worked fine 
`swig.render('/sample.html',{obj:object});`
but in documentation its mentioned to use like
`var template = swig.compileFile('/path');
  var output = template({obj:object});`
so please can someone explain me the difference between swig.compileFile and swig.render, and please explain any performance difference if any?

Answer (score 1):

`swig.compileFile` make a function(parse view and make javascript object) . When run this function you will get the layout `swig.render` ( it also logic inside `swig.render`). There isn't any performance difference